# Event handler called twice (angular)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatable

I am currently develops using angular datatables https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome

In the page that i built, it has button for adding new record (navigate to form component) and in the datatable it has action button in each row to edit and delete (navigate to form component (the same component for add new record))

function for add new record :

```
addNew():void{
        this._router.navigate(['../employee_termination_request_form/add/new'],{ relativeTo: this.route });
    }
```

column which has action button:

```
{
    data: null,
    width:'10px',
    render: function (data, type, row) {
        return `
        <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-inline-table dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" style="top:-10px; left:-125px">
        <span class="dropdown-item editBtnTransactTerminationRequest">Edit</span>
        <span class="dropdown-item deleteBtnTransactTerminationRequest">Delete</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        `;
    }
}
```

In OnNgInit i add the handler for the action button :

```
$(document).one('click', '.editBtnTransactTerminationRequest', ($event) => {
    this.editData();
});
```

When user click the edit button, then it will editData function which will redirect to form component.

```
editData():void { console.log(this.selectedData)
        if(this.toEdit=="1"){
            if(this.selectedData.requeststatus=="DRAFT")
                this.zone.run(()=>this._router.navigate(['../employee_termination_request_form/edit/'+this.selectedData.employeeid],{ relativeTo: this.route }));
            else{
                this.zone.run(()=>this.dialog.open(AlertDialog,{
                    data:{
                        dialogtitle:'Alert',
                        dialogcontent:'Request has been submitted and can not be edited!'
                    }
                }));
                $(document).one('click', '.editBtnTransactTerminationRequest', ($event) => {
                    this.editData();
                });
            }
        }else{
            this.zone.run(()=>this.dialog.open(AlertDialog,{
                data:{
                    dialogtitle:'Unauthorized Access',
                    dialogcontent:'You are not authorized to access this menu!'
                }
            }));
            $(document).one('click', '.editBtnTransactTerminationRequest', ($event) => {
                this.editData();
            });
        }
}
```

Now here is the problem, when user click Add Button, the page will load the form page and when they return and click the edit button. The handler for edit button will be callled twice. When i traced it with console.log, the first selectedData is empty (the value depends on what initialized in ngoninit) and the second one is the value of the row that i selected (the correct one). Can anyone help me figure out the solution for this?

Comment: use `ngAfterViewInIt` and call click function in it

Comment: still not work after being put in ngAfterViewInit

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix for my problem by unbinding the handler inside ngOnDestroy.

```
ngOnDestroy(){
    $(document).off('click', '.editBtnTransactTerminationRequest');
}
```